# Find a comformal mapping of rectangle domain onto upper half plane

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

Four vertices of rectangle domain are as follows:

$(0,0)$, $(0,k)$, $(k,i)$, $(0,i)$,  where $k>0$.

Any assistance that you can provide is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Closely related is this previous Question, [Schwarz-Christoffel mapping of the upper half-plane](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87551/schwarz-christoffel-mapping-of-the-upper-half-plane), which describes an inverse mapping, from upper half-plane to rectangle.

Comment: Seems to me that you may be able to use the Weierstrass $\wp$-function for an appropriate rectangular lattice. Any $\wp$ will map a fundamental domain two-to-one over the whole plane, and I think that with a rectangular lattice you should have $\wp(\bar z)=\overline{\wp(z)}$, meaning that the real line gets mapped to the reals. At this point, I get lost — this is definitely not my meat.