# Equal uncomputable integrals

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-integrals

I am reading Ahlfors' complex analysis.

He let $0<k<1$ and defined
$$K=\int_{-1}^1 \frac1{\sqrt{1-t^2} \sqrt{1-k^2t^2}}dz$$
$$K'=\int_{1}^{1/k} \frac1{\sqrt{t^2-1} \sqrt{1-k^2t^2}}dz$$
An exercise requires me to prove that $K=K'$ iff $k=(\sqrt{2}-1)^2$. So these are elliptic integral and I read online that in general, they cannot be computed. And since Ahlfors did not say much about it, I don't think we can compute $K$ and $K'$. So how do we approach?

Comment: You can find [some hints here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87551/schwarz-christoffel-mapping-of-the-upper-half-plane)

Comment: I have trie working on this but not sure what in that post suggests any hint here.